# ListView setOnClickLisiner

Tags: android, listview

I press a list item in my `listView`. How I can go to my another activity from list view item?
Please help me to understand how to solve this problem.

Here is my code if:

```
package com.example.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ListView listView;
Context context;
ArrayList prgmList;

public static int[] prgmImage = { R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_2,
        R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_2,
        R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_2

};
public static String[] prgmNameList = { "Let Us C", "c++", "JAVA", "Jsp",
        "Microsoft .Net", "Android", "PHP", "Jquery", "JavaScript" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList, prgmImage));

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your adapter plz ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement

```
OnItemClickListener
```

to your activity and set it to your listView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

...

...

listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Then you will get a new method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {

    Log.e(TAG, "Pos: " + pos);

}
```

Here you get the position of the licked item

Answer (score 0):

Hi for solving you're problem you need just to call this method `onListItemClick`.This method show witch row you select and you could set some intents as well.

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked row " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //go to another activity
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set an `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView` like:

```
final Context context = this;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        intent.setAction(context, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```